# InvalidOperationException: dispatcher processing is suspended on ImageOffsetProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher, invalidoperationexception

I am using C# and WPF and am trying to slide an image strip along the screen. I am being honest, I got the code from some code sample on the Internet and took the parts I needed from it.

```
public double ImageOffset
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            return (double)this.Dispatcher.Invoke(
               System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
               (DispatcherOperationCallback)delegate 
               { return GetValue(ImageOffsetProperty); }, ImageOffsetProperty);
        }
        catch
        {
            return (double)this.GetValue(ImageOffsetProperty);
        }
    }

    set
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
            (SendOrPostCallback)delegate 
            { SetValue(ImageOffsetProperty, (object)value); },
            (object)value);
    }
}
```

Sometimes when the program tries to get the ImageOffsetProperty an `InvalidOperationException: Cannot perform this operation while dispatcher processing is suspended` happens and I have no idea how to fix it.

I also tried `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`, safe the ImageOffsetProperty in a Double and then return it, but it always returned 0.

What is causing the `InvalidOperationException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about dropping all the `Background` stuff and just write a standard dependency property wrapper like this:

```
public double ImageOffset
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(ImageOffsetProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ImageOffsetProperty, value); }
}
```

When the property is set from a background thread, put the assignment in a `Dispatcher.Invoke` or `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` call.

Replace

```
obj.ImageOffset = someOffset;
```

by

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => obj.ImageOffset = someOffset);
```

or

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => obj.ImageOffset = someOffset);
```

if you don't have direct access to the `Dispatcher` property of some UI element.

Comment: Because then I most often get the `InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`..

Comment: Looks like the `ImageOffset` property is set in a background (non-UI) thread. Use `Dispatcher.Invoke` or `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` there.

Comment: As you see in the code, I did use Dispatcher.Invoke but at some point dispatcher processing is apparently disabled and execution is stuck. If I used Dispatcher.Invoke wrong, then please provide help on that .. I have no idea if I used it right ..

Comment: Not in the property wrapper, but simply where the property value is assigned. See my edit.

Comment: I think this might have actually worked. I still get an InvalidOperationException when trying to access the property without the dispatcher but then catch the exception using `Dispatcher.Invoke`, so I guess that's ok. Thanks for the help!