# WPF Inspector raises: Cannot perform this operation while dispatcher processing is suspended

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

when I'm trying to inspect my application there raises an error:

Cannot perform this operation while dispatcher processing is suspended.

```
        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                string _Value = "";
                //The next line throws the error:
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
                    {
                        _Value = (string)GetValue(ValueProperty); 
                    }));
                    return _Value;
                }
                set
                {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
                    {
                        SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
                    }));
                }
            }
            public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(RaVariable), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("0")
            {
                BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
                DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
            });
```

I have no idea why I get this error.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [InvalidOperationException: dispatcher processing is suspended on ImageOffsetProperty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589400/invalidoperationexception-dispatcher-processing-is-suspended-on-imageoffsetprop)

Comment: If I do that my UI is not responsing.